# Facebook sharer title and description not loaded

Tags: facebook

I've tried making a custom url with the format `sharer.php?u=<url>&t=<title>` and `sharer.php?p[title]=<title>&p[url]=<url>`, with the parameters encoded with both PHP functions `urlencoded` and `rawurlencode` (tried separately).

I've also tried the `<a>`/`<script>` solution at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/.

But it only shows the url as title and description. I have also tested the page with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, and corrected everything. I'm using `og:title`, `og:description`, `og:url`, `og:site_name`.

Running out of ideas here. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not doing anything for a day, this was suddenly working. Facebook is probably doing some caching

Answer (score 0):

facebook fetches meta-tag information before javascript loaded and redirected by short url

I got right response from below

1. I didn't use shorturl.
2. I put the meta-tags before rendering page
3. the url page's header can be loaded by anyone and anywhere.(it is not good if there is login error. make anyone can show the url page's header info)